# Making smaller product item detail on category grid

Tags: magento2, product, category-listing

> New to MSE so hello everyone.

I was wondering if there is something that makes the **product** item **description smaller** on the category **grid**. Because its really long now and I need to increase it. I looked into similar questions and searched Google but couldn't find any answer. I thought my topic title is clear enough.

Anyway, is there a way to get it smaller, I took a look in **attributes** for product item but no possibility to change any of that. Maybe I'm just in the wrong direction. Please help.

Here a screenshot for it:

[image: really long product item description]

Thanks for any help.

Ciao, Hessel

Comment: you want to character limit of description?

Comment: Hello @RakeshDonga Yes its really long now. Can I limit this:?

Comment: yes sure but you can get here product description ?

Comment: @RakeshDonga What do you mean with get here product description? :)

Comment: here you have which attribute get ? give me code

Comment: Best @RakeshDonga I'm new to M2 development. Do you need a specific code? I don't understand what you are asking. Sorry for that :)

Comment: yes i need to code so i will check it